# A lot of compilation errors in Boost intrusive list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, boost-asio

I have downloaded Boost.Asio lib and then connected it to microsoft visual studio 2017, I used this tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEF5U1AaIV8) . It works fine, but when I use boost intrusive list, it throws compilation errors.

I have tried a lot of versions of boost library but almost in all versions are same errors. Now I use 1.71.0 version of boost library.

Here is very simple code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "boost/intrusive/list.hpp"
int main() {
boost::intrusive::list<int> h;

}
```

I just want to make sure that it works without errors, but it throws a lot of errors.

Here is error list:

```
1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(55): error C2825: 
'T': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\get_value_traits.hpp
(145): note: see reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::default_list_hook_applier::apply<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\get_value_traits.hpp
(204): note: see reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::detail::supposed_value_traits<SupposedValueTraits,T,
true>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>          
SupposedValueTraits=boost::intrusive::list_defaults::proto_value_traits,
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1428): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::detail::get_value_traits<T,boost::intrusive::
list_defaults::proto_value_traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1455): 
note: see reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::make_list<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>d:\libcds-master\libcds- 
master\projects\win\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(7): note: 
see reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::list<int>' being compiled
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(55): error C2510: 
'T': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(55): error C3646: 
'type': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(55): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int 
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\get_value_traits.
hpp(145): error C2039: 'type': is not a member of 
'boost::intrusive::default_list_hook_applier::apply<T>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\get_value_traits
.hpp(145): note: see declaration of 
'boost::intrusive::default_list_hook_applier::apply<T>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\get_value_traits
.hpp(145): error C3646: 'type': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\get_value_traits
.hpp(145): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ 
does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(91): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::value_traits': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1456): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>' 
being compiled
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(91): error C2510: 
'value_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(91): error C3646: 
'pointer': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(91): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(92): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::value_traits': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(92): error C2510: 
'value_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(92): error C3646: 
'const_pointer': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(92): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(102): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::value_traits': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(102): error C2510: 
'value_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(102): error C3646: 
'node_traits': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(102): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(103): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::node_traits': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(103): error C2510: 
'node_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(103): error C3646: 
'node': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(103): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(104): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::
size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::node_traits': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(104): error C2510: 
'node_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(104): error C3646: 
'node_ptr': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(104): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(105): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::node_traits': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(105): error C2510: 
'node_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(105): error C3646: 
'const_node_ptr': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(105): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
default_header_holder.hpp(63): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a class 
or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(108): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::detail::get_header_holder_type<int,HeaderHolder>' being 
compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            
HeaderHolder=boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
default_header_holder.hpp(63): error C2510: 'ValueTraits': left 
of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
default_header_holder.hpp(63): error C2146: syntax error: missing '>' 
before identifier 'node_traits'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
default_header_holder.hpp(63): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
default_header_holder.hpp(63): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding 
';'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(108): error C2039: 
'type': is not a member of 
'boost::intrusive::detail::get_header_holder_type<int,HeaderHolder>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>         
HeaderHolder=boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(107): note: see 
declaration of 
'boost::intrusive::detail::get_header_holder_type<int,HeaderHolder>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            
HeaderHolder=boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(108): error C3646: 
'header_holder_type': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(108): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(54): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(111): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::detail::is_stateful_value_traits<int>' being compiled
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(54): error C2510: 'ValueTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(54): error C3646: 'node_ptr': unknown 
override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(54): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(55): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(55): error C2510: 'ValueTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(55): error C3646: 'pointer': unknown override 
specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(55): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(56): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(56): error C2510: 'ValueTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(56): error C3646: 'value_type': unknown 
override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(56): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(57): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(57): error C2510: 'ValueTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(57): error C3646: 'const_node_ptr': unknown 
override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(58): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(58): error C2510: 'ValueTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(58): error C3646: 'const_pointer': unknown 
override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(58): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(64): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(64): error C2653: 'ValueTraits': is not a 
class or namespace name
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(64): error C2269: cannot create a pointer or 
reference to a qualified function type (requires pointer-to-member)
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(67): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(67): error C2653: 'ValueTraits': is not a 
class or namespace name
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(67): error C2269: cannot create a pointer or 
reference to a qualified function type (requires pointer-to-member)
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(70): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(70): error C2653: 'ValueTraits': is not a 
class or namespace name
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(70): error C2269: cannot create a pointer or 
reference to a qualified function type (requires pointer-to-member)
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(73): error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(73): error C2653: 'ValueTraits': is not a 
class or namespace name
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\
is_stateful_value_traits.hpp(73): error C2269: cannot create a pointer or 
reference to a qualified function type (requires pointer-to-member)
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(113): error C3203: 
'header_holder_type': unspecialized class template can't be used as a 
template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(123): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::
list_defaults::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::header_holder_type>::value_traits': must be a class or namespace when 
followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(123): error C2510: 
'value_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(123): error C2993: 
'boost::intrusive::link_mode': illegal type for non-type template 
parameter 'link_mode'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(123): error C2903: 
'is_safe_autounlink': symbol is neither a class template nor a function 
template
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(123): error C2065: 
'value': undeclared identifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(123): error C2131: 
expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(123): note: a non- 
constant (sub-)expression was encountered
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(126): error C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::
list_defaults::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::
list_defaults::header_holder_type>::value_traits': must be a class or 
namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(126): error C2510: 
'value_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(126): error C2955: 
'boost::intrusive::link_mode': use of class template requires template 
argument list
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\options.hpp(180): note: see 
declaration of 'boost::intrusive::link_mode'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(142): error C2955: 
'boost::intrusive::value_traits': use of class template requires template 
argument list
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\options.hpp(110): note: see 
declaration of 'boost::intrusive::value_traits'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(149): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive
::list_defaults::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::header_holder_type>::data_t' being compiled
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(40): 
error C2825: 'ValueTraits': must be a class or namespace when followed by 
'::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(164): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::value_traits_pointers<ValueTraits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            ValueTraits=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(36): 
error C2510: 'ValueTraits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(40): 
error C2146: syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'node_ptr'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(40): 
error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(40): 
error C2903: 'rebind_pointer': symbol is neither a class template nor a 
function template
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(36): 
error C2039: 'type': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(40): 
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(42): 
error C2065: 'value_traits_ptr': undeclared identifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(42): 
error C2923: 'boost::intrusive::pointer_traits': 'value_traits_ptr' is not 
a valid template type argument for parameter 'Ptr'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(43): 
error C2903: 'pointer_traits': symbol is neither a class template nor a 
function template
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(43): 
error C2903: 'rebind_pointer': symbol is neither a class template nor a 
function template
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(43): 
error C2039: 'type': is not a member of 'boost::intrusive'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(50): note: see 
declaration of 'boost::intrusive'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(43): 
error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\detail\iiterator.hpp(43): 
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(164): error C2039: 
'const_value_traits_ptr': is not a member of 
'boost::intrusive::value_traits_pointers<ValueTraits>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            ValueTraits=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(163): note: see 
declaration of 'boost::intrusive::value_traits_pointers<ValueTraits>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            ValueTraits=int
1>        ]
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(164): error C3646: 
'const_value_traits_ptr': unknown override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(164): error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default- 
int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1289): error 
C2556: 'boost::intrusive::list_iterator<int,true> 
boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::s_iterator_to(boost::move_detail::unvoid_ref<void> &)': overloaded 
function differs only by return type from 
'boost::intrusive::list_iterator<int,false> 
boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::s_iterator_to(boost::move_detail::unvoid_ref<void> &)'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1270): note: see 
declaration of 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::s_iterator_to'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1288): error 
C2371: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::s_iterator_to': redefinition; different basic types
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1270): note: see 
declaration of 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults::header_holder_type>
::s_iterator_to'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1292): error 
C2062: type 'void' unexpected
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(59): error C2825: 'NodeTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1292): note: see 
reference to class template instantiation 
'boost::intrusive::circular_list_algorithms<int>' being compiled
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(59): error C2510: 'NodeTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(59): error C3646: 'node': unknown override 
specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(60): error C2825: 'NodeTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(60): error C2510: 'NodeTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(60): error C3646: 'node_ptr': unknown 
override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(60): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(61): error C2825: 'NodeTraits': must be a 
class or namespace when followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(61): error C2510: 'NodeTraits': left of '::' 
must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(61): error C3646: 'const_node_ptr': unknown 
override specifier
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\
circular_list_algorithms.hpp(61): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1292): error 
C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive
::list_defaults::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::header_holder_type>::value_traits': must be a class or namespace when 
followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1292): 
error C2510: 'value_traits': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1292): error 
C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1293): error 
C2059: syntax error: 'return'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1293): error 
C2825: 
'boost::intrusive::list_impl<int,boost::intrusive::
list_defaults::size_type,true,boost::intrusive::list_defaults
::header_holder_type>::value_traits': must be a class or namespace when 
followed by '::'
1>d:\boost_1_71_0\boost_1_71_0\boost\intrusive\list.hpp(1293): fatal error 
C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by using `boost::intrusive::list<int>`? Are you familiar with concept of intrusive containers?

Comment: VTT, i just want to test intrusive list, bacause i use libcds and  intusive list is used in libcds,  i just need to check if it compiles without errors  or not.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::intrusive::list<T>` uses members of your `T` which `T` has to provide. You can do this by inheriting from `boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<>` or creating a member `member_hook_` of type `boost::intrusive::list_member_hook<>`. This also means, you can't use primitive data types as `T`.

Here is the example from [the official site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/intrusive/list.html):

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class MyClass : public list_base_hook<>   //This is a derivation hook
{
   int int_;

   public:
   //This is a member hook
   list_member_hook<> member_hook_;

   MyClass(int i)
      :  int_(i)
   {}
};
//Define a list that will store MyClass using the public base hook
using BaseList = list<MyClass>;
//Define a list that will store MyClass using the public member hook
using MemberList = list<MyClass, list_member_hook<>, &MyClass::member_hook_>>;
```

You can choose between the member- and derivation-hook.